# Python: int(hexstr) vs. bytes.fromhex()

Tags: python, data-conversion, language-design

Consider constructing an int from a hex string, vs. constructing a bytes object:

```
hexstr = "FFF" # note there is an odd number of characters

int(hexstr, base=16)
Out[110]: 4095


bytes.fromhex(hexstr)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3319, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-107-0e5b955c6858>", line 1, in <module>
    bytes.fromhex(hexstr)
ValueError: non-hexadecimal number found in fromhex() arg at position 3
```

Everything works fine if we add a leading zero character:

```
hexstr = "0FFF"  # now we have an even number of hex characters
bytes.fromhex(hexstr)
Out[109]: b'\x0f\xff'
```

So int() can cope with an odd number of hex characters, but bytes.fromhex() cannot. 
Indeed, [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex) of bytes.fromhex() explicitly states that 2 characters per byte are required.

These are the facts, and I'm not disputing them.

Rather, my question is a language design question: what is the reason for this inconsistency? 
Why is it OK to assume the leading zero when converting to an int, but it's not OK when converting to bytes?

Answer (score 0):

`int(hexstr, 16)` takes the whole hexadecimal number and converts it an int.

`bytes.fromhex(hexstr)` on the other hand splits the input into pairs of hexadecimal digits, converts each of these pairs into a byte (a pair of hexadecimal digits can contain exactly the same range of values as a single byte, which is why hexadecimal is often used to represent binary data) and creates a bytestring out of all these bytes.

Those are different operations, so it's normal that they have different constraints on their inputs.